# Do YouTube Player error events correspond to permanent or transient problems?

Tags: youtube-api

Is there a possibility that a YouTube video (streamed with help from YouTube API) can temporarily be in some sort of banned state, making it dispatch errorEvents with errorCodes 100, 101, 150, only to eventually come back to a normal state that doesn't dispatch errorEvents?

In my implementation, I store some information about youtube videos in a database. I delete information about videos that dispatch these errorEvents, since videos that do not work are not in my interest to show. 
Now, the problem for me is if there is a video that only dispatches errorEvents for a short period of time, as it gets deleted from my system, but actually still works.

Is a common thing that videos temporarily or periodically dispatch errorEvents?

Answer (score 0):

[The Player API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#onError) gives an overview of reasons why onError might be triggered. You should be able to interpret from that whether the scenario you describe is likely or not.

For example, error `100` can be triggered when a video is private. It's obviously possible for the owner of a video to flip it back and forth between private and public, so whether you want to ignore that video id in the future is up to you—it depends on how likely you think it is that the video will be made public again.

Error `101` is triggered when a video isn't enabled for embedding. That's another option that can be changed by the owner of the video at any point. It's again up to you to determine whether you want to take the current state of the video into account and disregard that video id, or leave it in your system on the off chance that the owner makes it embeddable in the future.